# Getting Similarly-Named Keys from Redis Cache on Django web app

Tags: python, django, pandas, caching, redis

I am currently having trouble trying to cache a large Pandas DataFrame (300,000+ rows) that has 3 columns, an ID column and 2 large numpy array columns. I am unable to cache the whole DataFrame as one object since it is so large. So, I thought to cache by number, break up the DataFrame, and load them back in as chunks.

The number of rows in the DataFrame increase daily, so I will never know how many chunks of rows are cached. Therefore, I save them as 'encodings_df_1', 'encodings_df_2', ..., 'encodings_df_n'; where n is the highest number needed to cache all chunks of the original DataFrame.

Is there a way to get all the keys where it is like 'encodings_df_*', or is there an easier way to cache and load the original DataFrame back in?

EXAMPLE:

```
# Let's say the Pandas DataFrame 'df' currently has a length of 350
#I should have 4 objects cached in my Redis db:
# encodings_df_1, encodings_df_2, encodings_df_3, and encodings_df_4

# initial vars
chunk_size = 100
number_of_chunks = math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_size)

# upper and lower bounds for DF segmentation
lower = 0
upper = lower + chunk_size

# loop to cache DF chunks
for n in number_of_chunks:

    # cache key creation
    cache_key = 'encodings_df_' + str(n)

    # df slice to be saved
    if n == number_of_chunks - 1:
        temp_df = df.iloc[lower:]
    else:
        temp_df = df.iloc[lower:upper]

    # cache the slice
    cache.set(cache_key, temp_df, timeout=60*60)

    # adjust upper and lower
    lower = upper
    upper += chunk_size
```

If I do not know how many chunks there are, how can I load them all back in to get the original complete DataFrame?